# Arrays in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have the code below. Which takes the values for an array from a worksheet and calculated the sum and standard deviation.

```
Public Sub Example()


Dim numbers() As Long, size As Integer, i As Integer

size = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets(1).Columns(1))
ReDim numbers(size)

For i = 1 To size
    numbers(i) = Cells(i, 1)
Next i

For i = 1 To size

If numbers(i) > 10 Then
    Cells(i, 2) = numbers(i) + 3
 Else
 Cells(i, 2) = numbers(i) + 15
 End If

Next i
Debug.Print Application.WorksheetFunction.StDev(numbers)

Debug.Print Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(numbers)

End Sub
```

The sum works correctly but the stdev is slightly different than if I use the STDEV.P function in the worksheet itself.

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Are your numbers actually all integers? Or are there some with decimal parts?

Answer (score 2):

`StDev` and `StDev.P` are [two different functions](http://jonhaus.hubpages.com/hub/Microsoft-Excel-Standard-Deviation)

- `StDev` function evaluates a population sample
- `StDev.P` function evaluates a population

In your case, you can use

```
Debug.Print Application.WorksheetFunction.StDev_P(numbers)
```

depending on whether you are using sample data or entire population